# Pasting an image directly from a client clipboard

Tags: image, ckeditor, clipboard, internet-explorer-11, wysiwyg

We have a need to allow application users to paste images into WYSIWYG from.  Our front-end runs in IE 11. In cases when the image in case is actually a screen capture we really do not want to force users to first save and then upload it. It should be pasted directly (at least in terms of user experience) from Windows clipboard.

I was thinking of creating our own Image plug-in for `CKEditor`, but not sure if what we want is actually doable.

For example, [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#search=Clipboard) warns that

> Internet Explorer will display a security prompt for access to the OS
>   clipboard

Not sure what other difficulties we might face due to JavaScript guarding end-user file systems and other resources.

Since [CK Editor site](http://ckeditor.com/Forums/Support) refers to SO for support, I hope that someone here might be able to enlighten me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CKEditor 4.5 supports that. Test their demo.

Comment: Thank you. Somehow I missed it originally. It worked for me in IE and Chrome. Do you happen to know if a location where an image is saved easily configurable?

Comment: Yes, you just have to read their documentation and implement an uploader according to their API.